# Swift array struct

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

Consider:

```
struct abc {
    let def: Double 
}

func xyz(data : [Double]) {
    ...
}

var x: [abc]
```

I want to call `func xyz` with the `def` value first 6 elements of `x`.

I tried:

```
xyz(x[0...5].def)
```

How do I do this?

Comment: This question is wholly unclear.  It's impossible to guess what you want or need to do, especially as nothing here has good names (which is generally fine for a [so] question, bad for real code).  Do you want to call `xyz` multiple times with the arrays on the first six elements in the struct array called `x`?  Do you want to call `xyz` once with the total contents of the arrays on the first six elements of the array called `x`?  Do you want to call `xyz` with the first six elements of the `def` array of the first six elements in the array called `x`?  Or do you want something else entirely?

Comment: sorry guys, was in a hurry. def is a Double (not [Double]). so i need to call a func once with first 6 elements of x.def. xyz(x[0...5].def) doesnt work. array(x[0...5].def) also. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build an array of the `def` properties for the first six `x` items, you can use `map`:

```
let y = x[0...5].map { (object: abc) -> (Double) in
    return object.def 
}
xyz(y)
```

Or you can condense that to:

```
xyz(x[0...5].map { $0.def })
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all let's use more clear names

```
struct Numbers {
    var values: [Double]
}
```

### Computed Property

Now we can add a computed property to return the first 6 values

```
struct Numbers {
    var values: [Double]

    var first6Numbers: [Double] {
        let numElms = min(values.count, 6)
        return Array(values[0..<numElms])
    }
}
```

As you can see the code inside the computed property does check whether there are at least 6 elements into values. If so then it returns the first 6 otherwise it does returns as much elements as possible.

**Examples**

```
let fewNumbers = Numbers(values: [1,2,3])
fewNumbers.first6Numbers // [1,2,3]

let manyNumbers = Numbers(values: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
manyNumbers.first6Numbers // [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

### Function

Instead of always returning the first 6 values, we can use a function a specify (via a parameter) how many numbers we want into the result

```
struct Numbers {
    var values: [Double]

    func firstNumbers(numElms: Int) -> [Double] {
        let numElms = min(values.count, numElms)
        return Array(values[0..<numElms])
    }
}
```

### Tuple

We can also return an optional tuple of 6 Double.

In this case if there are at least 6 values into values then a duple of 6 Double is returned. Otherwise a nil value is returned.

```
struct Numbers {
    var values: [Double]

    var first6Values: (Double, Double, Double, Double, Double, Double)? {
        guard values.count >= 6 else { return nil }
        return (values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4], values[5])
    }

}
```

**Example**

```
let numbers = Numbers(values: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])

if let first6 = numbers.first6Values {
    print(first6.0)
    print(first6.1)
    print(first6.2)
    print(first6.3)
    print(first6.4)
    print(first6.5)
} else {
    print("Could not find at least 6 Doubles")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate the sequence like:

```
x[0...5].forEach { abc in
    xyz(abc.def)
}
```

or

```
for abc in x[0...5] {
    xyz(abc.def)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize an array with the same repeated value like this:

```
var threeDoubles = [Double](count: 3, repeatedValue: 0.0)
```

which would give:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```